# Barcode scanner with ZXing not working anymore

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, zxing

I have created a barcode scanner in C# for Windows Phone 8 using `ZXing.NET`. It worked fine but since this morning, it displays the error `Unable to initialize camera`. I haven't changed the code inside the page. Anyone familair with this problem or knows a solution?

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using Microsoft.Devices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using ZXing;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using ZXing.QrCode;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace PhoneApp2
{
    public partial class Scan : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private PhotoCamera _phoneCamera;
        private IBarcodeReader _barcodeReader;
        private DispatcherTimer _scanTimer;
        private WriteableBitmap _previewBuffer;

        public Scan()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // Initialize the camera object
            _phoneCamera = new PhotoCamera();
            _phoneCamera.Initialized += cam_Initialized;

            CameraButtons.ShutterKeyHalfPressed += CameraButtons_ShutterKeyHalfPressed;

            //Display the camera feed in the UI
            viewfinderBrush.SetSource(_phoneCamera);


            // This timer will be used to scan the camera buffer every 250ms and scan for any barcodes
            _scanTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _scanTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);
            _scanTimer.Tick += (o, arg) => ScanForBarcode();

            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }

        void CameraButtons_ShutterKeyHalfPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _phoneCamera.Focus();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            //we're navigating away from this page, we won't be scanning any barcodes
            _scanTimer.Stop();

            if (_phoneCamera != null)
            {
                // Cleanup
                _phoneCamera.Dispose();
                _phoneCamera.Initialized -= cam_Initialized;
                CameraButtons.ShutterKeyHalfPressed -= CameraButtons_ShutterKeyHalfPressed;
            }
        }

        void cam_Initialized(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Succeeded)
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                    {
                        _phoneCamera.FlashMode = FlashMode.Off;
                        _previewBuffer = new WriteableBitmap((int)_phoneCamera.PreviewResolution.Width, (int)_phoneCamera.PreviewResolution.Height);

                        _barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();

                        // By default, BarcodeReader will scan every supported barcode type
                        // If we want to limit the type of barcodes our app can read, 
                        // we can do it by adding each format to this list object

                        //var supportedBarcodeFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
                        //supportedBarcodeFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
                        //supportedBarcodeFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX);
                        //_bcReader.PossibleFormats = supportedBarcodeFormats;

                        var supportedBarcodeFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
                        supportedBarcodeFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.EAN_8);
                        supportedBarcodeFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.EAN_13);
                        supportedBarcodeFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.UPC_A);
                        supportedBarcodeFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.UPC_E);
                        supportedBarcodeFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.UPC_EAN_EXTENSION);
                        _barcodeReader.PossibleFormats = supportedBarcodeFormats;

                        _barcodeReader.TryHarder = true;

                        _barcodeReader.ResultFound += _bcReader_ResultFound;
                        _scanTimer.Start();
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Unable to initialize the camera");
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception myExc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myExc.Message);
            }
        }

        void _bcReader_ResultFound(Result obj)
        {
            // If a new barcode is found, vibrate the device and display the barcode details in the UI
            if (!obj.Text.Equals(tbBarcodeData.Text))
            {
                VibrateController.Default.Start(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
                tbBarcodeType.Text = obj.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
                tbBarcodeData.Text = obj.Text;
            }
        }

        private void ScanForBarcode()
        {
            if (_phoneCamera.IsFocusSupported == true)
            {
                //Focus when a capture is not in progress.
                try
                {
                    _phoneCamera.Focus();
                }
                catch (Exception focusError)
                {
                    // Cannot focus when a capture is in progress.
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                    {
                        txtDebug.Text = focusError.Message;
                    });
                }
            }


            //grab a camera snapshot
            _phoneCamera.GetPreviewBufferArgb32(_previewBuffer.Pixels);
            _previewBuffer.Invalidate();

            //scan the captured snapshot for barcodes
            //if a barcode is found, the ResultFound event will fire
            _barcodeReader.Decode(_previewBuffer);

        }

    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="PhoneApp2.Scan"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Canvas x:Name="viewfinderCanvas">

            <!--Camera viewfinder -->
            <Canvas.Background>
                <VideoBrush x:Name="viewfinderBrush">
                    <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform
                            x:Name="viewfinderTransform"
                            CenterX="0.5"
                            CenterY="0.5"
                            Rotation="90"/>
                    </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                </VideoBrush>
            </Canvas.Background>
            <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="txtDebug" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="462" FontSize="24" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="618" />
            <Path Data="M443.885,209.007 L248.921,209.007" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" UseLayoutRounding="False" Height="5" Canvas.Left="26" Canvas.Top="201.36" Width="143.77"/>
            <Path Data="M443.885,209.007 L248.921,209.007" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" UseLayoutRounding="False" Height="5" Canvas.Left="310.23" Canvas.Top="201.36" Width="143.77"/>
            <Path Data="M443.885,209.007 L248.921,209.007" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" UseLayoutRounding="False" Height="5" Canvas.Left="310.23" Canvas.Top="493.36" Width="143.77"/>
            <Path Data="M443.885,209.007 L248.921,209.007" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" UseLayoutRounding="False" Height="5" Canvas.Left="26" Canvas.Top="493.36" Width="143.77"/>
            <Path Data="M387.983,239.245 L387.983,399.76" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" UseLayoutRounding="False" Height="101.779" Canvas.Left="449" Canvas.Top="199" Width="5"/>
            <Path Data="M387.983,239.245 L387.983,399.76" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" UseLayoutRounding="False" Height="101.779" Canvas.Left="26" Canvas.Top="399.081" Width="5"/>
            <Path Data="M387.983,239.245 L387.983,399.76" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" UseLayoutRounding="False" Height="101.779" Canvas.Left="26" Canvas.Top="199" Width="5"/>
            <Path Data="M387.983,239.245 L387.983,399.76" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" UseLayoutRounding="False" Height="101.779" Canvas.Left="449" Canvas.Top="399.081" Width="5"/>
        </Canvas>
        <!--Used for debugging >-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="20, 0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbBarcodeType" FontWeight="ExtraBold" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbBarcodeData" FontWeight="ExtraBold" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: What does `e.Exception` say?

Comment: Confirm that the camera capability is still enabled in the package settings.

Comment: And where should I find the package settings? I have a file called packages.config but only displays a list with my installed packages..

Comment: Fixed it. Had to check the camera in device capabilities ;)